# Run jsTestDriver in WebStorm for Jasmine + Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine, js-test-driver

I am writing tests in Jasmine for a Backbone application and I want to know what proportion of the code my tests cover. For this goal I want to use jsTestDriver. But I have a problem: I created a config file and added all resources there, but when I start test Backbone methods don't define. This is my config file:

```
server: http://localhost:9876

load:
  - lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js
  - lib/jasmine-jquery.js
  - lib/JasmineAdapter.js
  - lib/sinon-1.5.2.js
  - cordova-2.2.0.js
  - libs/jquery-1.8.2.min.js
  - libs/underscore-min.js
  - libs/backbone-min.js
  - libs/lazyload-min.js
  - core/js/core.js
  - index.js

test:
  - spec/test.js
```

The order is the same as on SpecRunner file.  It is my test file:

```
describe("Attributes", function(){
    it("Test", function() {
        c = new Cars;
        expect(c.attributes.StartDate).toBeDefined();
        expect(c.attributes.StartDate).toBeDefined();
    })
});
```

Cars is a Backbone model and this model has default attribute StartSate. In my test I want check that this attribute defined. And ofcourse the mistake in WebStorm:

```
TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined
           at null.<anonymous> (spec/test.js:10:21)
```

Comment: what is `Model` ? Shouldn't it be `Backbone.Model` ?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse, I added description to the text about my test

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use the [`has`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-has) method of the model object to check for an attribute, rather than checking the `attributes` property:

```
describe("Attributes", function(){
    it("Test", function() {
        c = new Cars;
        expect(c.has("StartDate")).toBe(true);
    })
});
```

This way you can add some implicit logic to the model that can override the `has` method. Also, you didn't specify how you extended the model to create your `Cars` class. Have you specified default values?